# How to specify column of a table should be Indexed

Tags: indexing, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-6

Basically I have Table class specified. I am already using attribution like 
[Required]
I am trying to find out what is the attribute property to declare a column of table for Indexing. Any help appreciated. I am using version 5.x of the EnttityFramework. If required can upgrade to 6

Answer (score 1):

You can use `IndexAttribute` `[Index]`.

http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2014/02/15/ef-6-1-creating-indexes-with-indexattribute/